# Trouble with downloading images using Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting the following error when attempting to download images using a spider with Scrapy.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py",
line 61, in _set_url
            raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
        exceptions.ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

As best as I can understand it, it looks like I'm missing an "h" in a url somewhere? But I can't for the life of me see where. Everything works fine if I'm not trying to download images. But once I add the appropriate code to the four files below, I can't get anything to work properly. Could anyone help me make sense of this error?

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class ProductItem(scrapy.Item):
    model = scrapy.Field()
    shortdesc = scrapy.Field()
    desc = scrapy.Field()
    series = scrapy.Field()
    imageorig = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

**settings.py**

```
BOT_NAME = 'allenheath'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['allenheath.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'allenheath.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}

IMAGES_STORE = 'c:/allenheath/images'
```

**pipelines.py**

```
class AllenheathPipeline(object):
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        return item

import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url)

    def item_completed(self, results, item, info):
        image_paths = [x['path'] for ok, x in results if ok]
        if not image_paths:
            raise DropItem("Item contains no images")
        item['image_paths'] = image_paths
        return item
```

**products.py** (my spider)

```
import scrapy

from allenheath.items import ProductItem
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse

class productsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "products"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.allen-heath.com/"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/ilive-80/",
        "http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/ilive-112/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html'):
            item = ProductItem()
            item['model'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['shortdesc'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h3::text').extract()
            item['desc'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent').extract()
            item['series'] = sel.css('#pagestrip > div > div > a:nth-child(3)::text').extract()
            item['imageorig'] = sel.css('#prodsingleouter > div > div > h2::text').extract()
            item['image_urls'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent img').extract()[0]
            item['image_urls'] = 'http://www.allen-heath.com' + item['image_urls']
            yield item
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
    for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        yield scrapy.Request(image_url)
```

and here:

```
item['image_urls'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent img').extract()[0]
```

You are extracting this field and taking the first element. Which means that once you are iterating over it in the pipeline, you are in fact iterating over characters in the URL, which begins with `http` - explaining the error message you are seeing, as soon as the first letter tries to be processed:

```
Missing scheme in request url: h
```

Remove the `[0]` from the line. While you're at it, fetch the `src` of the image, instead of the entire element:

```
item['image_urls'] = sel.css('#tab1 #productcontent img').xpath('./@src').extract()
```

After that, you should update the next line also, in case the image url is relative, to convert it to absolute:

```
import urlparse  # put this at the top of the script
item['image_urls'] = [urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url) for url in item['image_urls']]
```

But you don't need this last part if the image URL in `src` is actually absolute, so just remove it.

Comment: Removing `[0]` got rid of that error. A new error popped up though. The line that immediately follows it combines the domain string with the image url. I did this in case the images used a relative path. (Though I don't think it's necessary for this site) The error is: `File "C:\allenheath\allenheath\spiders\products.py", line 24, in parse item['image_urls'] = 'http://www.allen-heath.com' + item['image_urls'] exceptions.TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects` If I remove that entirely my script runs with no errors. But then I still get no images.

Comment: Thank you. That solves the problem with that line. I can keep it in there and it doesn't error anymore. However, when I run it I still don't get any images downloaded. I exported my results to a csv and it is writing an `image_urls` column so I know it sees the images I want to grab. It's just not downloading them. I must be missing something else in another part of my code.

Comment: Here's an error I'm getting that will probably help. 

`2015-04-28 10:38:23-0700 [products] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.allen-heath.com%3Cimg%20class=%22alignnone%20size-full%20wp-image-5599%22%20src=%22http://www.allen-heath.com/media/iLive_80_3Q_Main.jpg%22%20alt=%22iLive_80_3Q_Main%22%20w
idth=%22770%22%20height=%22448%22%3E> (failed 2 times): DNS lookup failed: address 'www.allen-heath.com%3Cimg%20class=%22alignnone%20size-full%20wp-image-5599%22%20src=%22http' not found: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed.`

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'm still getting an error though. `2015-04-28 18:47:02-0700 [products] WARNING: File (code: 404): Error downloading file from <GET http://www.allen-heath.com/ahproducts/ilive-112/%3Cimg%20style=%22border:%204px%20solid%20black;%22%20src=%22http://www.alleheath.com/media/ilivefx.jpg%22%20alt=%22iLive%20FX%22%20width=%22320%22%20eight=%22225%22%3E> referred in <None>`

Comment: Phew, your css/xpath is all wrong and it doesn't extract the URL, rather the entire element. Check the update again.

Comment: Thanks for catching that! I knew I was having trouble getting just the URL, but I didn't know how to fix that. I suppose xpath was the only way? Everything is working now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I think you should be able to do it with css selectors also, but I don't use them much, prefer the xpath. Google for it a bit, you might find the solution if you want to avoid xpath.